# Flexbox container cannot be contenteditable in Chrome

Tags: css, layout, web, contenteditable, flexbox

The contenteditable attribute works correctly in Chrome, except when the editable element is also a flexbox container. What's going on here?

```
<p>Can be edited in Chrome:</p>
<div contenteditable="true"></div>

<p>Cannot be edited in Chrome:</p>
<div contenteditable="true" style="display:flex"></div>
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/openjck/rhrxatst/3/

Comment: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=963247

Comment: https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/750584/flexbox-causes-weird-behaviour-of-contenteditable

Comment: what do you mean by display:flex?

Comment: @Muhammad: If you don't know what that is, maybe you should move on to another question, since this question revolves entirely around that.

Answer (score 0):

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/rhrxatst/4/)

html

```
<p>Can be edited in Chrome:</p>
<div contenteditable="true"></div>
<p>Cannot be edited in Chrome:</p>

<!-- you need to have a flex-box container and set display style flex to this container -->

<div class="flexContainer">
    <div contenteditable="true" class="flexItem"></div>
</div>
```

css

```
/* respective css style for flexContainer and flexItem */
.flexContainer {
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -moz-flex;
    display: -ms-flex;
    display: flex;
}
.flexItem {
    -webkit-flex: 1 auto;
    -moz-flex: 1 auto;
    -ms-flex: 1 auto;
    flex: 1 auto;
}
```

Comment: This works, but there are some cases where the contenteditable element itself needs the display:flex rule. In particular, it appears that the only way to vertically center text and also use a scrollbar is to use display:flex (display:table-cell doesn't support scrollbars).